# Mock any Spring Bean in Test Class

Tags: spring, mongodb, mockito

I have Test class which I am using to test some mongo queries. 
My applicationContext-mongoclient.xml contents mongodb connection string.

I have my dao class which is annotated as `@component` and this mongoDatadase is autowired to dao

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContext-mongoclient.xml" })
public class ApplicationContextInitTest {

    @Autowired
    MongoDatabase mongoDatabase;

    MyDao myDao;
    @Before
    public void setMyDao(){
      estimateServicesLookup = Mockito.mock(EstimateServicesLookup.class);
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(estimateServicesLookup,"mongoDatabase",mongoDatabase);
  //@Test code here which is taking results from myDao and asserting. 


}
}
```

Above code is not working and looks like I am not getting mongoDatabase in my dao.
Can anyone suggest how we can do it?